# Find the number of week rows in a month

Tags: math, date-arithmetic

Given the start day (Wednesday = 4), and the number of days in a month (31), what is an elegant way to find the number of week rows a calendar of the month would require?

For the current month (startDay = 4, daysInMonth = 31), it would be 5. But if daysInMonth = 33, it would be 6 rows.

This doesn't quite work:

```
int numRows = (startDay+daysInMonth)/daysInWeek;
if ((startDay+daysInMonth) % daysInWeek != 0) {
    numRows++;
}
```

Comment: What is the first day in each row? Sunday or Monday?

Comment: You algorithm seems correct; what answer where you expecting?

Comment: It was mostly correct. See the chosen answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change to

```
int numRows = (startDay + daysInMonth - 1) / daysInWeek;
if ((startDay+daysInMonth - 1) % daysInWeek != 0) {
    numRows++;
}
```

and you should get the correct result.
EDIT: just to slightly expand on it : you have the right idea, you just forgot to account for the fact that the offset for day 1 is 0, not 1.

Comment: It is not correct. Please check with the month '2018/09'. It is missing one row. There should actually 6 rows but getting 5.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think your original algorithm is correct, just need to subtract 1 when doing modulo daysInWeek.

```
daysInWeek = 7
startDay = 3 # Zero based day of week array, 3 = Wednesday
daysInMonth = 31
numRows = (startDay+daysInMonth)/daysInWeek

if ((startDay+daysInMonth - 1) % daysInWeek != 0)
    numRows += 1
end

print numRows
```

It shows 6 correctly. (BTW, why do you need a month with 33 days?) It should be 6 rows for a 33 day month (if there was such a thing).

[image: 33 day month starting on Wednesday]

Comment: You're right, it does work for daysInMonth = 33. But for daysInMonth = 32, it should only return 5 weeks, but returns 6 instead.

Comment: Sorry, I made a change. You need to subtract 1 from the modulo line.

Answer (score 1):

```
int temp = daysInMonth;
temp = temp - (7 - startDay);
int result = ceiling(temp / 7) + 1;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. If daysInMonth = 33 and startDay = 4, I get 5 rows. Should be 6.

Comment: @soleil well do the math by hand. 33 - (7 - 4) = 30. 30 / 7 = 4.28... celing = 5. 5+1 = 6

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic way to do it in C#, which works by counting the Saturdays in a month and then adding one if there's any left over days. Since it literally reads a calendar like a human would, there's no strange calendar arithmetic needed. It's all offloaded to the C# `DateTime` code, we just piggyback off that.

I chose Saturday because most calendars go Sunday (far left) to Saturday (far right). You can just choose a different day if you wish to denote the end of a week.

```cs
public static int RowsForMonth(int year, int month)
{
     int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
     int rows = 0;
     int i = 0;
     while(i < days)
     {
          i++;
          DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, i);
          if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || i == days)
               rows++;
     }
     return rows;
}
```

```
Jan 2022 -> 6
Feb 2022 -> 5
Mar 2022 -> 5
```